# Not null margin of span in wrapper-div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/JYkUS/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>FSou1::Верстка макета</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logo-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="90" height="90" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-text">
                <span>Happy Nanny</span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="first"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NEWS & PRESS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FIND JOB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-text">
                <span class="easy-way">THE EASY WAY</span>
                <span class="find-the-best">TO FIND THE BEST</span>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <p>babysitters, childminders, nannies or private tutors</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Span with text

```
<span class="easy-way">THE EASY WAY</span>
```

as default has margin-left, but i don't know why. I really don't want to set a negative value to margin-left. Is it possible to align this span to left border and why does it now have margin with such value?

P.S. Watched in Google Chrome (firefox doesn't have this margin)

[image]

**EDIT:**

Just if i remove this style:

```
.logo-wrapper .logo, .logo-wrapper .logo-text {
float: left;
}
```

my span goes to left border =\ but why is it so?

**EDIT2:** Other way, to move `<div class="clear"></div>` from 'logo-wrapper' container, to root-level as

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="logo-text"></div>
            <div class="menu"></div>
            <!-- FROM HERE -->
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div> <!-- MOVE HERE -->

        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-text">
                <span class="easy-way">THE EASY WAY</span>
                <span class="find-the-best">TO FIND THE BEST</span>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <p>babysitters, childminders, nannies or private tutors</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But still can't understand, why floating still work after inner clear:both div

**EDIT3:** Is it because float:right menu even goes "righter", than div with clear:both?

Comment: don't see a margin on `.easy-way` in chrome 25

Comment: As u can see, i have so. Version chrome 25.0.1364.152 m =\

Answer (score 1):

The margin is actually applied on the body tag.  You can remove it using:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F7E5;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JYkUS/2/

This is commonly handled using a `reset.css` file which removes all browser specific styling from the page, so you can start from a single base point when creating a cross browser compliant webpage.  I would recommend applying such a strategy to the site.

Comment: It doesn't work =\ I need align 'THE EASY WAY' to left border, as logo image (where is p left border)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you haven't set the body `margin` to `0`

Make it `margin:40px 0 0 0`

```
body {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    background: #f8f7e5;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JYkUS/3/)**

Comment: Did u check the demo?? it s working there. http://jsfiddle.net/JYkUS/3/ check this I have added bg color for clarification

Comment: In ur example 'THE EASY WAY' in Google Chrome start as logo left border? I dont have so =\

Comment: Need to margin this to left border, as logo image